# How to compare Lists in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

How can this test fail?

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Get_Code()
{
    var expected = new List<int>();
    expected.AddRange(new [] { 100, 400, 200, 900, 2300, 1900 });

    var actual = new List<int>();
    actual.AddRange(new [] { 100, 400, 200, 900, 2300, 1900 });

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    // Assert.AreSame(expected, actual)       fails
    // Assert.IsTrue(expected.Equals(actual)) fails
}
```

Answer (score 461, accepted):

To make assertions about collections, you should use [`CollectionAssert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx):

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

`List<T>` doesn't override `Equals`, so if `Assert.AreEqual` just calls `Equals`, it will end up using reference equality.

Comment: I wish this gave more detailed messages when it failed. "Different number of elements" and "Element at index 0 do not match" are slightly useless. *What are they then?!*

Comment: If you don't care about item order: {A,B,C} == {C,B,A}, then use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243779.aspx

Comment: Note that `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` can be noticeably slower than `Assert.IsTrue...SequenceEqual`

Comment: @MarkSowul: But it comes with much better failure diagnostics, right?

Comment: It's so slow I'd rather do `if (!SequenceEqual) { CollectionAssert.AreEqual }`

Comment: @MarkSowul: Hmm... sounds like that's worth reporting as a bug then. No reason it should be that bad.

Comment: We were using it to compare byte arrays (`MemoryStream.ToArray()`) -- 50-150 ms for `SequenceEqual`, 500ms - 1s for `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`.  Probably for smaller collections it's a negligible difference but presumably it doesn't scale well.

Comment: I was using Assert.AreEqual and couldn't find the issue.

Comment: If an argument does not implement `ICollection` (e.g., because it is of type `IList`), use `actual.ToList()` to make it an `ICollection`.

Answer (score 49):

I guess this will help

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
```

Comment: That was my fall-back too, but I'd hope that CollectionAssert would provide more helpful failure messages.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't really: "CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)" (what are the elements?)

Comment: Second that, twice as fast as CollectionAsser.AreEqual for my byte array with 300k elements

Comment: Does this work with custom-made objects or only lists of primitives? I have a list of objects (my own class) and it doesn't seem to work with it.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to check that each contains the same collection of values then you should use:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
```

Edit:

> "Two collections are equivalent if they have the same elements in the same quantity, but in any order. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object." - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243779.aspx

Answer (score 20):

I tried the other answers in this thread, and they didn't work for me and I was comparing collections of objects that had the same values stored in their properties, but the objects were different.

Method Call :

```
CompareIEnumerable(to, emailDeserialized.ToIndividual,
            (x, y) => x.ToName == y.ToName && x.ToEmailAddress == y.ToEmailAddress);
```

Method for comparisons:

```
private static void CompareIEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> one, IEnumerable<T> two, Func<T, T, bool> comparisonFunction)
    {
        var oneArray = one as T[] ?? one.ToArray();
        var twoArray = two as T[] ?? two.ToArray();

        if (oneArray.Length != twoArray.Length)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Collections are not same length");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < oneArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var isEqual = comparisonFunction(oneArray[i], twoArray[i]);
            Assert.IsTrue(isEqual);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice addition, or you can also override the `Equals` method and the `CollectionAssert` will work.

Answer (score 7):

this test compares a date input, checks if its a leap year, if so, outputs 20 leap years from the inputted date, if not,
 outputs the NEXT 20 leap years, myTest.Testing refers to the myTest instance which in turn calls the values from a List called Testing containing the calculated values required. part of an exercise I had to do.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            int testVal = 2012;
            TestClass myTest = new TestClass();
            var expected = new List<int>();
            expected.Add(2012);
            expected.Add(2016);
            expected.Add(2020);
            expected.Add(2024);
            expected.Add(2028);
            expected.Add(2032);
            expected.Add(2036);
            expected.Add(2040);
            expected.Add(2044);
            expected.Add(2048);
            expected.Add(2052);
            expected.Add(2056);
            expected.Add(2060);
            expected.Add(2064);
            expected.Add(2068);
            expected.Add(2072);
            expected.Add(2076);
            expected.Add(2080);
            expected.Add(2084);
            expected.Add(2088);
            var actual = myTest.Testing(2012);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Fluent assertions does deep comparisons of arrays `actualArray.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedArray)`

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me, though I could see via debug my lists were equal. A variation on this answer worked: actual.ShouldDeepEqual(expected);

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AdminUser> adminDetailsExpected = new List<AdminUser>()
{
new AdminUser  {firstName = "test1" , lastName = "test1" , userId = 
"001test1"  },
new AdminUser {firstName = "test2" , lastName = "test2" , userId = 
"002test2"   }
};
```

//Act

```
List<AdminUser> adminDetailsActual = RetrieveAdmin(); // your retrieve logic goes here
```

//Assert

```
Assert.AreEqual(adminDetailsExpected.Count, adminDetailsActual.Count);  //Test succeeds if the count matches else fails. This count can be used as a work around to test
```