# MS Test failing with a collection

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm starting with MS Test and trying to run following test. I see following part gives me a fail, which is quite suprising:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EachRetailerPassedToBuilderIsReturnedInVmList()
    {
        List<string> mockRetailers = new List<string> { "Asda", "Tesco" };

        Assert.AreEqual(new List<string>{ "Asda", "Tesco"}, mockRetailers);

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

> Result Message:   Assert.AreEqual failed.
>   Expected:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `List<T>.Equals` does not provide elementwise check of data. It will only compare references. Quick solution would be to iterate through data and `Assert.Equals` on each element. Remember though to check if list sizes are equal beforehand.

It is also possible to use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` to get appropriate result.

[How to compare Lists in Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055632/how-to-compare-lists-in-unit-testing)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055632/how-to-compare-lists-in-unit-testing

Comment: actually it looks like this is a duplicate question, which I did not see before. The CollectionAssert worked for me.

Comment: Oh. I have completely forgotten about CollectionAssert.