# How to compare two lists or arrays or list and arrays have the same content?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, compare, assert

How to compare two lists or arrays or list and arrays have the same content? Any easy way to do it? What I can figure out is to loop to compare all the elements one by one. I use the comparison in Unit Test by using Assert? Which `Assert` method should I use? Use `Assert.AreEqual`?

Comment: Check this please; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055632/how-to-compare-lists-in-unit-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243736.aspx).

```
var a = new[] { 1, 2, };
var b = new[] { 1, 2, };
var c = new[] { 3, 4, };

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a, b); //passed
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(b, c); //fails
```

There are other methods on collection assert to help with what you might be asserting about your collections, in case `AreEqual` isn't what you want.