# C# unit testing with collections of collections

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

To piggyback on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055632/2658159)...

How does this test fail?

```
[TestMethod]
public void DummyTest() {
    var expected = new List<List<string>>() {
        new List<string>(){ "123456", "25.6", "15", "a" },
        new List<string>(){ "123457", "3107450.82", "1", "bcdef" },
        new List<string>(){ "123458", "0.01", "900000", "-fgehk" }
    };

    var actual = new List<List<string>>() {
        new List<string>(){ "123456", "25.6", "15", "a" },
        new List<string>(){ "123457", "3107450.82", "1", "bcdef" },
        new List<string>(){ "123458", "0.01", "900000", "-fgehk" }
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

By the way, `Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));` also fails.

Is there a better way to test collections of collections?

Using .NET 4.6.1.

Comment: To add to this, the test fail result message is: "CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 0 do not match.)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That comparison method is going to look at the first item from each collection, check **using the default comparer for that type** if they're equal, and if not, consider the outer collections unequal.  It'll then go on to check the other elements in the same manner.

The default equality comparer for `List<string>` is going to compare the references of the two objects, not compare the underlying values of the two lists, because `List` doesn't change that default behavior from `object`.

You could write your own `IComparer` that knows how to checks if two collections are actually equal, and provide that comparer to `CollectionAssert`, if you want the items in the inner collections to be compared using the values of the items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this is using the following code:

```
public static bool AreEqual<T>(IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
{
    if (list1?.Count != list2?.Count)
        return false;

    // order does not matter. Remove OrderBy, if it matters
    // return list1.OrderBy(_ => _).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(_ => _));
    return list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
}

public static bool AreEqualListOfLists<T>(IList<List<T>> lists1, IList<List<T>> lists2)
{
    return lists1.All(innerList1 => lists2.Any(innerList2 => AreEqual(innerList1, innerList2)));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var expected = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"123456", "25.6", "15", "b"},
        new List<string> {"123457", "3107450.82", "1", "bcdef"},
        new List<string> {"123458", "0.01", "900000", "-fgehk"}
    };

    var actual = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"123456", "25.6", "15", "b"},
        new List<string> {"123457", "3107450.82", "1", "bcdef"},
        new List<string> {"123458", "0.01", "900000", "-fgehk"}
    };

    var areEqual = AreEqualListOfLists(expected, actual);
}
```

It is slightly longer than the `SelectMany` solution, but it allows more flexibility (e.g. if order does not matter at deeper level, it can be easily adjusted or provide meaningful error message on difference).