# How to compare IReadOnlyCollection<bool> to List<bool> for equality by value?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a unit test to compare actual results to expected results, where the class I am testing gives me a IReadOnlyCollection and my expected results are List.

I read over the this answer about comparing Lists using CollectionAssert at [How to compare Lists in Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055632/how-to-compare-lists-in-unit-testing), however when I attempt to do so, I get compiler error "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection' to 'System.Collections.ICollection'"

Here is my test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void EveningMotion()
    {
        IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider = new MockDateTimeProvider(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0));
        ILightHardwareInterface frontyardLights = new MockLightHardwareInterface();
        MockLightHardwareInterface backyardLights = new MockLightHardwareInterface();

        LightController controller = new LightController(dateTimeProvider, frontyardLights, backyardLights);
        controller.ActuateLights(true);

        IReadOnlyCollection<bool> actualResult = backyardLights.GetRecording();
        List<bool> expectedResult = new List<bool>
        {
            true
        };

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
```

What is one to do? I kind of want to keep the expected and actual results comparison rather than iterating through both element by element, if possible.

Comment: `String.Join` and compare the strings?

Comment: Are you using a specific Assertion library or is that just the default one that MS uses? Also, Core or what framework version?

Comment: @matti Just the built in unit test stuff. Framework 4.5 on VS 2015.

Comment: Even if they were both `List<T>` that approach will not work. Loop through and compare them or better yet do what icepickle has suggested above.

Comment: `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`?

Comment: Assert that length of your constructed list == lenght of readonly collection + assert IsTrue for `ReadOnly.Single() == List.Single()`

Comment: That's doing a reference comparison, try [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243736.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @juharr " cannot convert from IReadOnlyCollection<bool> to System.Collections.ICollection "

Comment: @ChristopherPisz actualResult.ToList()

Comment: @SirRufo ToList method does not exist on IReadOnlyCollection

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Computer says: "It does." https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Try `new List<bool>(actualResult)` instead or add `using System.Linq`

Comment: The [second highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11055746/3744182) from the linked question should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CollectionAssert for collections.

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
```

Comment: cannot convert from IReadOnlyCollection<bool> to System.Collections.ICollection

Comment: What is the concrete type of IReadOnlyCollection result?
If it is System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection, you can cast it to ICollection.

Comment: Problem solved doing it that way. Side question, Is casting via CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedResult, (ICollection)actualResult); type safe? I thought it was akin to a reinterpret cast in C++ (I am still a C# noob) and that there would be an "as" method if it was safe.